Загрузка зависимостей для плагина C# WPF
Есть своя система плагинов для программы, мне надо реализовать динамическую загрузку зависимостей для определенных плагинов, чтобы не добавлять эти зависимости в саму программу, если придется написать какой-либо другой плагин.
Есть такой код, который вроде как загружает зависимости:
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;

private Assembly? ResolveAssembly(object? sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var name = args.Name.Substring(0, args.Name.IndexOf(',')) + ".dll";
    foreach (var i in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.GetValue<string>(SettingsParamConsts.ParameterPath.p_PathToDeps), "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if(i.Contains(name))
        {
            var raw = File.ReadAllBytes(i);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(raw);
            return assembly;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

Но возникает следующая ошибка, при попытке создать экземпляр класса DefinitionEvaluator: System.MissingMethodException: "Method not found: 'Void Scap.Api.DefinitionEvaluator..ctor(Scap.Bridge.Schema.Ns)'."
В чем может быть проблема и какие есть альтернативные решения?

Меня учили так, что я должен в своей программе знать, что делает каждая строчка и отвечать за тот код, который использую и пишу. И не важно мой код это или нет. Попробуйте досконально разобраться, что тут происходит.
